# can I only access part of returned items in Python function?

Tags: python, function

Here's an example of my question, suppose I have the function:

```
def xsq(x):
    return x, x**2,x**3,x**4,x**5
```

If I just need the 3rd and 5th element, is there a simpler way I can access them, instead of assigning 5 objects and call the function? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of how you are currently doing it?

Comment: Just use `xsq(x)[2]` and `xsq(x)[4]` to get the 3rd and 5th elements of the return value.  If you want them both, do `r = xsq(x)` and then use `r[2]` and `r[4]`.

Comment: You can only ever return *a single object*. Here, you are returning a `tuple`. You can just index into that tuple for whichever index you are interested in.

Comment: @smac89 I was trying something like `a,b=xsq(2)[2,4]` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through tuple-unpacking:

```
def xsq(x):
    return x, x**2,x**3,x**4,x**5
```

Here we call the function and only assign real names to the third and fifth elements

```
_, _, third, _, fifth = xsq(n)
```

Note that in the above case, you still get 5 objects but since we only care about the third and fifth we bind them to unique variable names and `_` acts as a dummy variable

Comment: The left hand side can again modified with `*_, third, _, fifth`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM hmm interesting. It's nice, but it kinda changes the meaning of the variable called `third` to mean `third-last`, and `fifth` to `last`. That may or may not be an issue, but I don't think it's worth the obscurity

Comment: Oh yes! Make sense!. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access only the required index.

```
def test():
    return "A", "B","C","D"

print(test()[2])
print(test()[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

`xsq` returns a tuple, which you don't have to unpack. Assign it to a variable and use indices to get the values

```
x = xsq(2)
print(x[2], x[4]) # 8 32
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above example you provided Python will create a tuple and return the value.(Comma separated return values are returned as tuple).

So If you want to get the element at position 3 you will need:

```
def xsq(x):
    return x, x**2,x**3,x**4,x**5

x = xsq(5)
#OR
a,b,c,d,e=xsq(5)
#a,b,c,d,e will have individual values

print(x[2])
```

output:

```
125
```